# Adding a recurring date to a vector

Tags: java, date, loops, vector, deprecated

I am still using the deprecated setYear() on Java for my calendar program and somehow it displays the same year like this:

Wed Dec 21 00:00:00 CST 2022

Wed Dec 21 00:00:00 CST 2022

Wed Dec 21 00:00:00 CST 2022

```
//loop in another method
for (int i = realYear-1900; i <= realYear-1900+10; i++){
    date.setYear(i);
    vectorEvents.add(new Event(date, title));
}
textArea.setText(displayEvents());

//events method
public String displayEvents(){
    String data ="";
    Event e;
    for(int i=0; i<vectorEvents.size(); i++){
        e =  vectorEvents.get(i);
        data += e.date + "\n";
    }
    return data;
}
```

I tried displaying after adding the first date and then displaying again after adding the second. It seems to change the first date to the latest year the same as the second one. Is there another solution for this or there is just something wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Are you restricted to JDK classes or can you use joda time?

Comment: Looks like you keep updating the same Date instance. Put `new Date()` in your loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding the same `Date` object 10 times to a vector (which shouldn't be used anymore either, BTW). So at the end of the loop, every reference in the vector points to the same Date object, containing the last year you set on it.

You need to instantiate a new Date at each iteration:

```
for (int i = realYear-1900; i <= realYear-1900+10; i++){
    Date copy = new Date(date.getTime());
    copy.setYear(i);
    vectorEvents.add(new Event(copy, title));
}
```

Comment: thank you man i love you! tried that but I did copy = date; thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

`Date` objects are mutable in Java and, as other have pointed out you are using only one instance and changing it.

If the `Event` object is yours, the best solution in the long term is to change the constructor and create a copy of the `Date` passed (making a defensive copy in the terms of Bruce Eckel in "Effective Java").

```
public Event(Date d, String title) {
    this.date = new Date(d.getTime());
    this.title = title
}
```

Notice how you don't need to do the same with the `title` since `String`'s are inmutable.

Comment: +1 for the defensive copy. I tend to consider and use Date as an immutable object (as it should have been from the start), assuming everybody does the same, but it seems some people continue mutating dates :-(